# Profile page buttons are wonky

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

On my user profile page, when I click on the green bar under "next privilege" or the black button under "newest", the blue buttons it shows are not centred and are touching the text. Is this just for me, or is it supposed to be like this for some reason?

[image: The green bar]

---

[image: The black button]